# Double grub entry of windows 10. I want to remove it

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am having double grub menu entry of windows 10. I am not saying that 40_custom grub file located in /etc/grub.d

That is a different case. Here Windows has double entries and fun fact that both the entries load the same OS.(I have one windows installation)

`Sourcing file /etc/default/grub`

`Sourcing file /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg`

`Generating grub configuration file ...`

`Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic`

`Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic`

`Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic`

`Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic`

`Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf`

`Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin`

`Found Windows Recovery Environment on /dev/sda1`

`Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda2`

`Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda3`

`done`

This is what I get from `sudo update-grub`

Both entries load the same OS. From disks app it shows that windows is on /dev/sda3/ and on /dev/sda2 there is system reserved partition. And on /dev/sda1/ there is system recovery partition.

IDK how it can boot from reserved partition and I also don't know which entry to remove. So please suggest and if data loss of **only windows** happens then okay. I formatted windows(resetted).

[EDIT]

Here is what I get from `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

`GRUB_DEFAULT=0`

`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`

``` GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=``lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian ```

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

Comment: Can you shopw us the contents of your grub file please? If you have nano type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` from a terminal when you are loggen into Ubunit. Or use gedit in place of nano.

Comment: you can tell grub to skip one of the filesystem in your case /dev/sda2 or /dev/sda3.  `sudo lsblk -f` please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a record that windows can be booted from it. When you installed windows twice or even if another windows no longer exist, still there may be a record of windows so to fix this problem,

Start windows in recovery. The old F8 key no longer works so, Open windows, login then Click Start, Click power and hold the shift key on your keyboard, and while holding the key, click "Restart" option. It should show a screen saying please wait

Then your pc may reboot. Again open windows. Now go to "Troubleshoot" then "Advanced options" and open "Command Prompt". Again your pc will reboot. Then again open Windows 10 then it will say "Preparing Command Prompt" or " Please wait" depending on your windows 10 version.

Now it will give you list of Administrator users. just click your user account name then type your password.

Now a Command Prompt Window should open. There type these commands

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd

bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot
```

Then close command prompt by typing  `exit`.
Now select "Turn off your PC"

Then turn your pc on again and this time there should be Only ONE Windows 10. If there are still other windows boot entries, Try executing `sudo update-grub` In linux. Then your problem should be fixed.

NOTE: There are also many other methods you can try if this method does not works.

Thank You

Comment: "fixmbr" isn't applicable to UEFI based computers, i.e., any from the last decade.